# relatively open sets

Tags: general-topology

Definition of a *relatively open set*:

$ D \subset K^N $ is a set.
$U \subseteq D $ is relatively open in D if 
$$ U = \emptyset \quad$$ or
$$     \forall x \in U \quad \exists \quad r > 0 \quad | \quad B(x,r) \cap D \subseteq U$$

What I want to know is: is there a set U with $x \in U \subseteq D  $ such that  $ B(x,r) \cap D \nsubseteq U$.

Example:

If $D = (0,2] $ and $ U =[1,2]$
and $x = 2$, then $B(2,r) \cap D = (2-r,2]  \subseteq U$.

In the above example I dont see for any $x \in U$ where $ B(x,r) \cap D \subseteq U $ is not  satisfied.
Can someone please give examples of $D $ and $ U $ where $ B(x,r) \cap D \subseteq U $ is not  satisfied.

Comment: How about $x=1$ in your own example? If $r>0$ then $B(1,r)\cap D$ will contain elements that are not in $U$.

Comment: what if $x=1,r=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @drhab, if $x =1$, then $B(1,r) \cap D = (1-r, 1+r) \subseteq U$
I was reading $B(1,r) \cap D $ as take elements that are common to both $B(1,r) $  and $U $ instead of $B(1,r) $  and $D $

Comment: No. If $0<r<1$ then $B(1,r)\cap D=(1-r,1+r)$

Answer (score -1):

Definition of a relatively open set, U must be in D, but D=(0,2] and U=[1,2] , U is not in D, this is D in U, your example is not a counterexample